# difference of the two parameters in method like - (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameters, touches

when i try to figure out how to deal with the touches in iOS, i saw some code use the first parameter "touches" some uses the second one "[event allTouches]". so anyway, what's the difference between them. in what situation use the first one, what situation use the second one. THANKS!
here's more details:

```
// used the first parameter
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSUInteger touchCount = [touches count];
    NSUInteger tapCount = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];
    methodStatus.text = @"touchesEnded";
    touchStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d touches", touchCount];
    tapStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
   @"%d taps", tapCount];
}

// used the second parameter
-(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UIEvent has property called timestamp along with the touches. Apart from that I believe both are same.